# OpenJPA 2.1.1 enhancement problem on Glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, openjpa

My problem is this exception:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.1.1-r422266:1148538 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "
```

I'm trying to get an very simple java application with jsf and jpa running, but there seems to be a problem with the enhancement of my entities. As far as I know, tries OpenJPA to enhance my entities at runtime, which are listet in the `persistence.xml`, however there is no agent to do this. The keyword for this is: `Enhancing at Runtime`, right?

I thought the enhancement will automatically done by the application server at deployment? How can I configure this?

My exactly environment:

- Glassfish 3.1.1
- Derby, which is integrated in Glassfish
- OpenJPA 2.1.1
- Mojarra JSF 2.1.3

**Update #1:**

After some comments I've added the following lines to my `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false"/>
<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
```

It works now, but OpenJPA throw this warning:

```
SEVERE: 52  myApp  WARN   [http-thread-pool-8080(5)] openjpa.Enhance - Creating subclass for "[class myApp.model.entities.AbstractEntity, class myApp.model.entities.Post]". 
This means that your application will be less efficient and will consume more memory than it would if you ran the OpenJPA enhancer. Additionally, lazy loading will not be available for one-to-one and many-to-one persistent attributes in types using field access; they will be loaded eagerly instead.
```

I think this can't be the solution.

**Update #2:**

Refer to fvu's answer, I've tried to define the `-javaagent` jvm parameter in the `domain.xml` and over the web admin console. After a restart appeared the problem again.

**Update #3:**

Refer to update #2, I've played a bit around. There must be thrown an error, when the `-javaagent` parameter is used, but the file is missing, right?. Yes, there it is:

```
Waiting for domain1 to start .Command start-domain failed.
Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /tmp/openjpa.jar
```

If I copying the agent to this location, this error doesn't appear, but openjpa could still not enhance my entities!

Comment: Not an answer, by why don't you use Eclipselink, the JPA implementation that comes with GF?  Just wondering...

Comment: I've used OpenJPA in a few java se projects, so it's a question of homogeneity. On the other hand, you show me thats no homogeneity in the environment... hrmm

Comment: Note that JPA is like many other Java APIs an **abstract** API. As long as you don't use implementation-specific features (i.e. no one of your `import`s refer to OpenJPA), then your JPA code should work equally fine on another JPA implementation.

Comment: Is the enhancement part not dependent from implementation?

Comment: Enhancement to me looks like what Eclipselink calls weaving, the bytecode manipulation of the entity classes.  This improves performance and allows some enhanced features.  The application should work without, if you allow unenhanced classes (with the openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=supported jvm option)

Comment: So now it works but suboptimally.  I agree, that's probably not the solution, but at least it allows you to run the app while continuing the search for a solution.

Comment: @openscript.ch Just for curiosity, why don't you want to enhance entities at build time? Don't know if you use Maven; if so, that's quite an easy thing with openjpa-maven-plugin.

Comment: Check out this article here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721962/does-openjpa-work-well-with-glassfish  that suggests to fall back to build time enhancement and locates the libs in the global lib directory (location of libs in GF is sometimes a bit tricky).  But wondering more than ever if it's worth all that trouble...

Comment: @MaDa: That will work. As I have enhanced the entities by hand it works too. I don't want to be stubborn, but I'll try to get the other solution running.

Comment: @fvu: You're right, it's a good point to leave `OpenJPA` for the moment, but I'm still interested in solutions.

Comment: wondering why it expects the openjpa jar in /tmp....

Comment: ..because I've defined it in vm options and I'm sure that the .jar was there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still having issues... I'd highly recommend biting the bullet and setting up [build time](http://webspherepersistence.blogspot.com/2009/02/openjpa-enhancement.html) enhancement. You'll be much happier in the long run if you get that going.

Comment: For learning: Is this only recommended in context with openjpa or in all cases?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question... but setting up build time enhancement is the way to go. Get it working as a part of your build process. When writing code / running unit tests in an IDE(eclipse), I'd recommend using the javaagent.

Comment: I mean is it recommended to enhance at build time with OpenJPA or is this recommended with any jpa implementation?

Comment: Enhancement isn't required for all JPA providers.

Comment: I'll try it on weekends or when I've time and give you a feedback. Thanks!

Comment: +1 but having doubts wrt the portability issues between JPA implementations caused by that approach...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

- add the Java agent for enhancement to GF's JVM option, see [this link](https://support.newrelic.com/kb/docs/installing_java_agent_on_glassfish) for an example of how to install a javaagent and OpenJPA's doc 5.2.3, enhancing at runtime.  That emulates enhancer activation in desktop apps as closely as possible IMO.

However, when I read chapter 5.2.4 of the OpenJPA docs it might be capable of picking up the correct enhancer automatically.  Try copying `openjpa.jar` to the domain's library directory, and check what happens after a server restart.

Comment: Since I've started, `openjpa-all-2.1.1.jar` is in the domain's library directory.

Comment: Glassfish ignores the `-javaagent:/tmp/openjpa.jar` parameter. I've tried it with the `domain.xml` and the admin console.