# Enhancing OpenJPA entity in runtime in jboss

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss7.x, openjpa

I am not able to run my spring mvc+openjpa applicaton on jboss AS 7.1.x in my windows laptop.
After deployment when i execute it, it says -

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Attempt to cast instance "com.caobusiness.selfcare.entity.DummyTable@1698b9" to PersistenceCapable failed.  Ensure that it has been enhanced.
```

After searching, i found that open jpa entities needs to be enhanced either during built time or run time. I am trying to enhance entity during runtime using javaagent, but it fails.

my jboss standalone.conf looks like

```
#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:D:\openjpa-2.2.0.jar"   
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

I do not want to go for built time enhancement as of now. I have gone through posts [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294906/openjpa-2-1-1-enhancement-problem-on-glassfish-3-1-1/7336781#7336781) and [why enhancement is needed](http://webspherepersistence.blogspot.in/2009/02/openjpa-enhancement.html)

Will appreciate some leads.

Comment: Can anyone point me to any leads if you dont have any solution ??

Comment: I doubt that just adding the Javaagent works. JBoss (and any application server) does a ton of classloader trickery and manipulation. Therefore the enhancer doesn't see / miss the classes he would need to enhance. I guess you need to add the enhancer your deployment. However I've no idea how to do that, since I'm not using J2EE at all.